# consuming wcf on mvc project fails after published

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using a sms panel in my website which provides me with a api to use, when I'm debugging the system and use it locally it works perfectly but when I publish the website it gives the following error:

`A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 87.107.121.54:80`

and this is the code I'm using

```
SendSoapClient client = new SendSoapClient("SendSoap");
ArrayOfString receivers = new ArrayOfString();
receivers .Add("0920xxxxxxx");
ArrayOfString result = client.SendSimpleSMS("username", "password", receivers, "sender number", "message goes here", false);
```

I've put the call to the web service inside my global.asax file just to check if it works or not and it just doesn't work. what exactly am I doing wrong here ?

P.S: I've used this api service in my other websites which are not mvc projects, but just asp.net website and they all are working fine, this is the first time using it in mvc project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the computer you deployed your application to doesn't have network access to the `87.107.121.54` IP address which is where the API is hosted. So talk to your network administrator and make sure that the server on which your ASP.NET MVC application is running has network access to this address. Since it is on port 80, I suppose that there shouldn't be issues with the firewall, but nevertheless, you should check that as well. There's nothing wrong with your code, it's more of an infrastructure and network connectivity problem.

Comment: It's not possible, because my other websites are hosted on the same server and they are all using the very same API as being used in this project, and they are working fine.

Comment: Well, read the error message once again and you will see that it is telling you that there's a connectivity problem to this IP address. Once again there are 2 possible reasons: network connectivity or firewall blocking the HTTP call.

Comment: Yea I know that, I'm not saying what you're saying is wrong, actually that was the first thing that came to my mind as well but then how my other websites are working with it, then I don't know. How exactly can I troubleshoot this than calling the network admin? in case if he's not available.

Comment: Ok it seems a serious one and you were exactly right about the network access, because I tried browsing the webservice link and it failed while it worked on my own pc. do you think it might be the firewall??

Comment: As I said there are 2 possibilities: network access or firewall.

Comment: you were right, it was a network access to that IP. thanks a bunch